# Question about bleeds from Illustrator to Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, print-design, bleed

I have a vector file, created in Illustrator. I added 0.125" bleeds to it. It's all fine. However, when I export the file to PSD the guides disappear in Photoshop... and I wondered if there's an easy way to mark the bleeds that are already added in Illustrator to the exported file, when opened in Photoshop. I'm sorry if I didn't explain clearly enough what I mean. Hope the pictures below clarifies more:

[image]

Comment: Are the Illustrator layers marked as "show" and "print" or just "show"?  I would *guess* that only "print" layers are shown when you import to PS, but I don't have PS to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you saving out as PSD?

You should save as PDF and then your bleeds and trim marks, etc will show just fine...

What's happening is: when you save to PSD everything outside of the artboard is tossed.

Here's the same AI file, first as PSD, then as PDF:

[image: PSD 1]

[image: PSD 2]

[image: PDF 1]

[image: PDF 2]

(I added a white background layer to make the trim marks easier to see)

~~~~~~~~

If you really must save to PSD for whatever reason, then just add your own trim marks:

- Select your background (green) layer
- Go to Object > Create Trim Marks
- Go to Object > Artboards > Fit to Artwork Bounds
- Transform your background layer so that it extends out just slightly past your trim marks

Before (as viewed from within Illustrator):

[image: Bleed guides]

[image: Bleed guides close]

In the images above, the black line on the inside denotes the artboard bounds, the red line is the bleed guide and outside of that is the artwork bounds

After:

[image: Trim marks]

[image: Trim marks close]

In the above images the artwork bounds are on the inside, in the four corners stroked paths act as trim marks, and the artboard bounds are on the outside having the effect of leaving some transparency (or whitespace) between the artwork bounds and the artboard bounds...